# Use Google Credentials to Login in to the SharePoint 2013 Foundation server without using Azure Access Service (ACS)

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-2013

I want to achieve Open Authentication in SharPoint 2013 without ACS.
Here is my Scenario.

I have FBA configured site in SP2013.
I have also created one custom login page which will be used to provide three buttons to the user

1.SharePoint Login
2.Google 
3.Microsoft

1.SharPoint Login
  When user click on this button, it will redirect to the standard sharepoint login page with a drop down with Windows Authentication and Forms Based Authentication.

2. Google (Need Help with this)
   When user click on this button, It should open a page or user should be redirected to page where Google Ask for the Allow Deny buttons to the user.
   According to the selection , user should be provided and access to the Sharepoint site.
3. Microsoft (Need help)
   Same as above but it will redirect to Microsoft login page.

Please help with this.
I dont want to use paid products or ACS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own **Security Token Service** which you then register in SharePoint as trusted token issuer.

But authentication is only one part to provide access for users. If you want authorize single user from microsoft or google, you would need to write a custom claim provider to provide identities for the authorization.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but can we do it without writing custom STS? Do you have any working example for this/

Answer (score 0):

You can use google api's and write custom sts and set it as Trusted Identity provider for sharepoint login.
Google developer allows you to create projects and it gives you API's which can be used in the custom sts code which you write and authenticate.